# If a woman's husband is with her in heaven, will he also get virgins?

Tags: quran, hadith, hadith-interpretation

From a woman's point of view, will her husband be with her in heaven?  If so why will the man get virgins? Will the man have the wife he loves and virgins?

Comment: Yes, he will have both. However, his wife from dunia would be the the most beautiful out of all virgins.

Answer (score -1):

If the woman wants her husband, the husband will be with her. 
Now you're asking about why hoor will be with him, the verse of the Quran which speaks about hoor, needs some detailed explanations. I won't go in to details now as it's not possible in a single comment, I will say in short. 
Hoor can be used for both genders, male and female and hoor means a person with extreme whiteness of the white part of the eye. And it's someone purified. So it can mean a person from this world, like your spouse, or it can mean hoor al ayn. Hoor also means a spouse, a companion, a friend, a loved one. So if you want your husband, you will get him, and if you husband wants you, he will get you Inshallah. In that case, you are your husband's hoor and your husband is your hoor. 
Regarding 72 virgins, if I remember correctly, that's only for Martyrs, someone who was a Shahid, and them 72 virgins are for serving - help. That's all I remember about this Hadith. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Down viote as your views should be backed by ISlamic references